# Mysqli prepared statements register

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch, statements

Okay I have one question. I need to check if the user already exists but the question is now what I need to type in the `if()` I can't fetch because I have closed but if I didn't close i got an error because there can't run 2 statements. So I think if there are someone who can help me? I have the rest code but I only give the code here.

Here is my code:

```
$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username=?");
$result->bind_param("s", $username);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($username);                                
$result->close();

if (){
$register = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user 
                    (username, password, email, rr, rank) 
                     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$register->bind_param("sssii", $username, $kode, $email, $rr, $rank);
$register->execute();
$register->close();                                 
} else {
    echo "User already exists!";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: more logical statement

```
$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username=?");
$result->bind_param("s", $username);
$result->execute();
$found = $result->fetch();                        
$result->close();

if ($found){        
    echo "User already exists!";                                          
} else {
    $register = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user 
                    (username, password, email, rr, rank) 
                     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $register->bind_param("sssii", $username, $kode, $email, $rr, $rank);
    $register->execute();
    $register->close(); 

}
```

Comment: It making if the username exists its saing the echo "User already exists!"; and putting data in with the same name, but if it didn't exists it didn't say something and didn't put data in

Comment: It said the user already exists but it didn't exists and it didn't put some data into the database.

Comment: what do you see when you do `echo $found;` right before the if statement?

Comment: Sorry I've read the doc not good enough (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)..... false is only returned when an error occured --> new update

Comment: So what I need to do now?

Comment: I already updated the script, look at the changes I have made http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28462328/revisions

Comment: It work and if the user exists it said it, and if the user not exsits it didn't say something. But it didn't put into the database.

Comment: Try removing `$result->bind_result($username);`

Comment: Finally :) pfff (I'm not an expert, I've learned something too).... Just click the arrow up and the 'check' mark next to the answer ;)

Comment: Where?? Sorry i am new on stackoverflow :D